# Facebook sharing is successful when use test user,but failed when use real Facebook account

Tags: ios, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-ios-sdk

I want to add Facebook sharing function to my iOS app. I want people can post their feeling about my app on Facebook. Now I can use test users to share successful. But When I use real Facebook account to share, it fails. Xcode says `error code:200,error description:(#200) Permissions error`.
I passed reviewing of "publish_actions", and I am not in developing mode.
I'm sure my code is right,because I use other people's app secrete to share and it works well.
I don't use Facebook official SDK,and I use ShareSDK.

Comment: what error you are getting?

Comment: @Ashutosh error code:200,error description:(#200) Permissions error

Comment: This is just because you have enabled sandboxing in your app's setting for facebook, once you disable it, it will be live for all users.

Comment: @Ashutosh I have disabled sandboxing in Status&Review, but it doesn't work.

Comment: Have you added permissions array while sending request on facebook?

Comment: I didn't use Facebook official SDK,and I use ShareSDK.So I don't know. I'm sure my code is right,because I use other people's app secrete to share and it works well.

Answer (score 0):

Most probably in app delegate where you have added permissions you have not requested for all required permissions like following example:

```
// To open session of facebook and close it
- (BOOL)openSessionWithAllowLoginUI:(BOOL)allowLoginUI {
    NSArray *permissions = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:
                            @"email",
                            @"user_likes",
                            @"user_friends",
                            @"user_about_me",
                            @"user_relationships",
                            @"user_birthday",
                            @"user_location",
                            nil];

    if (! [[FBSession activeSession] isOpen]) {

        return [FBSession openActiveSessionWithReadPermissions:permissions
                                                  allowLoginUI:allowLoginUI
                                             completionHandler:^(FBSession *session,
                                                                 FBSessionState state,
                                                                 NSError *error) {
                                                 [self sessionStateChanged:session
                                                                     state:state
                                                                     error:error];
                                             }];
    }
    else {
        return [FBSession openActiveSessionWithReadPermissions:permissions
                                                  allowLoginUI:allowLoginUI
                                             completionHandler:^(FBSession *session,
                                                                 FBSessionState state,
                                                                 NSError *error) {
                                                 [self sessionStateChanged:session
                                                                     state:state
                                                                     error:error];
                                             }];

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is on ShareSDK.The ShareSDK isn't updated when official Facebook SDK is updated. So I ask for beta ShareSDK to solve the problem.